# MySQL Duplicate Entry Error on non-primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table defined with a single primary/auto-increment key.

[image]

When I call the following query I receive an error.

```
INSERT INTO device_sensor_reading (`we_id`, `UNIX_time`, `temp_we_id`, `reading_format_id`,`log_id`, `msg_type`, `device_position`) VALUES
(79995, 1550896918, 0, 3, 1, 0,1);
```

Error: 08:43:39 call sits_db.`Insert Simulated Data`()  Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '79995-1550896918' for key 'we_id_UNIX_time'  0.063 sec

Neither we_id or UNIX_time are specified as UNIQUE in my table so why does MySQL give me this error?

Comment: Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE device_sensor_reading` - Then you can see all keys.

Comment: Given that the value reported in the error is not a value you are (directly) passing in, I suspect you have an insert trigger on the table that is generating the error.

Comment: You probably have an unique index. Check the create table as Paul suggest. mrore info here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/

Comment: Yuo don't see the check in the `UN` column for `UNIX_time` and `temp_w_id`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The data is actually passed in the query `79995, 1550896918`.

Comment: You're correct. MySQL workbench did not show this level of granularity. I'll need to modify the table using SQL commands and forget trusting the UI.   PRIMARY KEY (`reading_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `we_id_UNIX_time` (`we_id`,`UNIX_time`),
KEY `temp_we_id` (`temp_we_id`),
KEY `log_id_reading_base_idx` (`log_id`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a combined UNIQUE KEY. MySQL allows you to combine two columns, which results that only the combination of both values is unique.

Comment: Yes, you're right. MySQL workbench did not show this unique key relationship. I had to call 'SHOW CREATE TABLE device_sensor_reading' to see that there was a unique key relationship.

Comment: Your error message did already say that there is a combined key: `key 'we_id_UNIX_time'` and `entry '79995-1550896918'`

Comment: Yes. I know it did. But the UI did not tell me this so I was confused. In fact the UI showed that either UNIX_time or we_id did not need to be unique. Only after I called the query above did the issue become clear. Lesson learned, MySQL workbench does not show everything I need

Answer (score 0):

In your table you specified `w_id`, `temp_w_id` , in your query are `we_id` and `temp_we_id`, now, check if you have any value with this entry in two fields. Now is the same with `log_id`... Maybe unique field is repeating

Comment: Good catch but that typo is because I'm modifying the actual query to protect my customer's data. I don't want to be publishing their schemas for the world to see.